# Are there any ways to glean useful analysis information from a comments field?

Tags: reporting

I have a dataset of data and two of the fields are user comments - (I did not design this form)

I would like to know if there is anything I can do to get any information from a comments field - are there any best practices out there to make use of this type of data in a report / analysis ?

Otherwise is this data useless?

Comment: The first thing to do would be to count how many users made comments.  The second would be to read (some of) them to see what kind of information they contain.

Comment: Good call - a correlation with the comment and the user (I do have a user field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a text mining type approach to try and identify sentiment (ie positive or negative comments). [R](http://cran.r-project.org/) is capable of doing this if you make use of the [tm](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/index.html) (text mining) package.

There's a tutorial on this sort of analysis here: [Mining Twitter for consumer attitudes towards airlines](http://jeffreybreen.wordpress.com/2011/07/04/twitter-text-mining-r-slides/)

Here's some more in depth info on text mining using R: [Text Mining in R](http://www.rdatamining.com/examples/text-mining)

Answer (score 1):

You can make a word cloud. Here's the [Wordle](http://www.wordle.net/) implementation, which is pretty easy to use and has several nice features. Some people really hate them with a passion that should be reserved for exploding 3-D pie charts, but I think they can be edu-taining. Here's a [balanced presentation](http://junkcharts.typepad.com/junk_charts/files/NYDataViz1.pdf) from Kaiser Fung.

Comment: +1 Great idea - I guess I could try out combinations of words / counts and remove my common words like And The A etc.